# Integrating Spring with JSF2

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I work on a project with `jsf2` `spring` and `hibernate`.
When I want to integrate jsf2 with spring, I have this error when starting my JSF in `tomcat7`. I have the jars **myfaces-impl & api**. I searched the Internet, but found no solution until now.

```
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/TagHandler
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2823)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:205)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:289)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:365)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:351)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:299)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:248)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:313)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.TagHandler
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
... 25 more
```

**web.xml :**

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>RichFaces Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>RichFaces Filter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

**faces-config.xml :**

```
<application>
<el-resolver>
org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
</el-resolver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `jsf2` libraries. If you have added it then it is not in your classpath.

Comment: yeah ,i have already added jsf2 libraries ( jsf-impl ,jsf-api ,jstl ). and there are present in my classpath ( i chose build path -->libraries --> add jars ) . these steps are already done ,but it shows me these errors .

Comment: i resolved the problem . all what i've to do is to change jsf version from 1.5 to 2 .

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to use old facelets jars in JSF 2, because the implementation bundles facelets VDL. Instead, it seems some JSF 1.2 libraries are used in a JSF 2 app, which is not right. Just update your libraries if you are using JSF 2.

Comment: i'm following a tutorial ,and i added libraries as mentioned , so i think it's a problem of starting listener .